# How remove IIS on Windows 8

Tags: windows, iis

Default Web Site in IIS 8 not working because "Service W3SVC was not found on computer" and I am trying to fix that by reinstalling IIS but I cannot remove it.

I removed everything from Add Remove Programs that contains Internet Information Services or IIS, restarted computer but IIS still wasn't removed.

How I can remove IIS?

Comment: How do you check if it was removed?

Comment: I am simply opening it: Type IIS in search and in results here is Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager

Comment: Open an elevated  PowerShell and run the following command, what does it show? 'dism.exe /online /get-features /format:table | where {$_ -match "IIS"} | where {$_ -match "Enabled"}'

Comment: Note that the IIS Management Console (at least on Windows 7) is very distinct from IIS itself. The IISMC connects to an IIS, which can run on any system you have access to (not just the local system). W3SVC is IIS (or at least its HTTP component).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIS is a Windows Feature, use the Turn Windows features on or off link on the site to remove Internet Information Services and Internet Information Services Hostable Web Core. That should technically remove it.

If that doesn't do it, post up what you're seeing.